# Crash when I send pointers to a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a traversable linked list, but my program crashes when I try to add an element to the list. I've tried many things but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
typedef struct node_t node_t;
typedef struct list_t list_t;

struct node_t {
    void *data;
    node_t *prev;
    node_t *next;  
};

struct list_t {
    node_t front;
    node_t back;
};

list_t* listEmpty () {
    list_t *list = malloc (sizeof (list_t));
    list->front.prev = NULL;
    list->front.next = &(list->back);
    list->back.prev = &(list->front);
    list->back.next = NULL;
    return list;
}

void listPushFront (list_t *list, void *data) {
    node_t *newNode = malloc (sizeof (node_t));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->prev = &(list->front);
    newNode->next = list->front.next;
    list->front.next->prev = newNode;  //CRASHES HERE
    list->front.next = newNode;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    list_t *list = malloc (sizeof (list_t));
    int a = 6; 
    void* pa = &a;
    listEmpty(list);
    listPushFront (list, pa);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would an empty list need two nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listEmpty()` returns a list, and has a void argument. In `main()` however you pass it a list, and don't capture its return value.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t node_t;
typedef struct list_t list_t;

struct node_t {
    void *data;
    node_t *prev;
    node_t *next;  
};

struct list_t {
    node_t front;
    node_t back;
};

list_t* listEmpty (void) {
    list_t *list = (list_t *)malloc (sizeof (list_t));
    list->front.prev = NULL;
    list->front.next = &(list->back);
    list->back.prev = &(list->front);
    list->back.next = NULL;
    return list;
}

void listPushFront (list_t *list, void *data) {
    node_t *newNode = (node_t *)malloc (sizeof (node_t));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->prev = &(list->front);
    newNode->next = list->front.next;
    list->front.next->prev = newNode;
    list->front.next = newNode;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    list_t *list = 0;
    int a = 6; 
    void* pa = &a;
    list = listEmpty();
    listPushFront (list, pa);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the compiler doesn't complain because it is running in C89 mode and the `listEmpty()` definition doesn't provide a prototype (it needs an explicit `list *listEmpty(void)` to provide a prototype.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How is that related to prototype? It doesn't complain over C99 neither: http://liveworkspace.org/code/55B5Q$4

Comment: It depends on your compiler options, but if you compile with GCC and options such as `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition` you will get warnings, which you can fix (and, IMO, it is worth using the options and fixing the problems it identifies).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Of course. But it has nothing to do with C89, you'll get the same result if `-std=c99` replaced with `-std=c89`

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not being initialized properly and this is leading to the crash.

```
listEmpty(list);
```

should be

```
list = listEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong in so many ways.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    list_t *list = malloc (sizeof (list_t));
```

Why are you doing this in `main`?

Why do you call `listEmpty` with parameter `list`?

```
listEmpty(list);
```

Your `listEmpty` function doesn't do anything with the parameter you pass to it.

You're not doing anything with the pointer that your `listEmpty` returns, so how do you expect it to propagate to the following call of `listPushFront`?